# Show image when I have an especific error

Tags: javascript, html, mikrotik

I use MikroTik hotspot, and I have an error. I would like to show an image chat.git when this appears

The code is

```
$(if error)<script type="text/javascript">
var error = "$(error)";
if (error == "simultaneous session limit reached") {
<img src="/chat.gif" alt="Chat Here"> 
}
else if (error == "invalid password") {
document.write("Contrasena erronea");
}
else if (error == "no valid profile found") {
document.write("Tiempo terminado, consigue otra Ficha.");
}
else if (error == "User $(username) not found") {
document.write("Mete bien el usuario.");
}
else document.write("$(error)")
</script>$(endif)
```

Answer (score -1):

HTML

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

Script

```
$(if error)<script type="text/javascript">
  var error = "$(error)";
  if (error == "simultaneous session limit reached") {
    var url = '/chat.gif';
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = "https://1147.3cx.cloud/callus/#apwifi";
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = url;
    link.appendChild(image);
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(link);
  } else if (error == "invalid password") {
    document.write("Contrasena erronea");
  } else if (error == "no valid profile found") {
    document.write("Tiempo terminado, consigue otra Ficha.");
  } else document.write("$(error)")
</script>$(endif)
```